# Is it OK to have a foreign key (without indicating for which table)?

Tags: database

I have multiple tables (A), (B) and (C)

and I have a table (D) which has the field (target_type) and (target_id), where (target_type) can be one of the following ("A", "B" or "C"), and (target_id) is a biginteger that (has no foreign key constraints at all),

is that OK?

Comment: foreign keys should model your domain. Failure to do will often lead to a world of pain. Sometimes, we remove FKs in high insertion scenarios, but then the code doing the inserting is responsible for referential integrity

Comment: If you want to enforce data integrity, then it would be necessary to set up the foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes, that's fine. But in practice, you may find that the joins are inefficient, and you quickly get into a situation where table D is out of sync with the ABC tables due to no referential integrity being enforced (if you DELETE a row from ABC and don't update D to match).

Generally, when I see a table structure like this, it is because the model is wrong somewhere. Not always. But generally.

Are you sure that your model is right?